# Sonatype nexus admin login

Tags: nexus

I'm having a problem which I can't solve.

I have bought a cheap vps, with ubuntu 12.10 then installed the tomcat7, maven, and nexus. All of them are the latest. This is a fresh install from everything. I started and deployed the nexus, no errors in catalina, no errors in nexus, and when I tried to login with admin/admin123, I have failed.

I'll show you any of my log file what you need, please help me with this.

**EDIT**: nexus is 2.2-01

**EDIT2**: this is a cheap server with 512 ram, running without X

My security-configuration.xml is this:

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<security-configuration>
    <version>2.0.3</version>
    <enabled>true</enabled><!-- was true -->
    <anonymousAccessEnabled>true</anonymousAccessEnabled>
    <anonymousUsername>anonymous</anonymousUsername>
    <anonymousPassword>{1FH7iFzhCukHI3ISkjq+AuQZb+bOMrB70bGqF2y6fNE=}</anonymousPassword>
    <realms>
      <realm>XmlAuthenticatingRealm</realm>
      <realm>XmlAuthorizingRealm</realm>
    </realms>
    <securityManager>default</securityManager>
</security-configuration>
```

Comment: Have you tried hand editing the xml file to set enabled to false and restarting Nexus?  This is supposed to remove the password prompts so you can get in and reset things.

Comment: I have the same problem now. I installed 2.2.01 on another server which does not have this problem. Changing `true` to `false` also did not work

Comment: my problem was my fault.

I started the bundle, not the war file. in that case these suggestions can not worked for me. after that, i start over everything, use the war file on the 8080 port, and everything worked.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Do the following:

1. stop Nexus
2. change the enabled in the xml to false
3. restart Nexus
4. get in without anything as admin that way
5. reset the admin password
6. enable the security again in the user interface

Oh and btw. I would suggest to run Nexus from the bundle with Jetty on a VPS and not with the war file in Tomcat so you get more performance out of it.

Update: Security can no longer be disabled in Nexus 2.7 and up. You have to insert an admin user into the xml as documented in [this support page](https://support.sonatype.com/entries/24893021-How-can-I-reset-a-forgotten-admin-password-).

Answer (score -4):

Resting nexus admin password from default "admin123" to more secured password without changing config files.

I got my nexus instance up and running with no issues login in as admin user and default password. I wanted to reset admin password ( to more secure password) and followed the following instructions (without touching the security.xml file as i hate changing config files to do any password resets)

1. Login to nexus with admin user and default password.
2. Click on server link under administration tab.
3. Make sure that SMTP settings are set up correctly ( hostname , port
   , username and passowrd).
4. Click on "Test SMTP settings" and provide an email address to see if
   you get mail from nexus server.
5. If you have already set up SMTP correctly on your instance you don't
   need to run step 3 and 4.
6. Hit "Users" link under Security tab and select admin user. make sure
   you have set up the correct email for this user.
7. Log out of nexus .
8. Login and hit forgot your "password" link.
9. The password recovery screen will prompt you for user which is
   "admin" and email should be the one you have listed in step 6.
10. Hit "Reset Password" button and you ll get a much stronger password
     in email .

Again Checking SMTP settings and admin user's email is one time action. Step  8 to 10 take less than a minute and one can easily reset admin password without touching the security.xml file. Ofcourse this file will be automatically updated as soon as you login with new password. Preferred way than modifying the file manually.

Comment: you are so funny. how can you login, if you can not login? :)

Comment: With default username/password as admin/admin123 you can login

Comment: Lol, the original question says clearly he can't login with the default admin/admin123 user and password.